# Spring security filter not working as intended

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

The spring blocks all the requests (throws 403) even though i have added a filter to allow a specific URL which is authenticated.

Could someone explain me why this is happening?

```java
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        try{

             http
                     .authorizeRequests(
                            auth -> auth
                                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/RemoteHandlerServices/Handle").authenticated()
                                    .antMatchers("/**").denyAll()
                     )
                     .oauth2ResourceServer()
                    .jwt()
                    .jwtAuthenticationConverter(getJwtAuthenticationConverter());
            http.headers().contentSecurityPolicy(CONTENT_SECURITY_POLICY);
            return http.build();

    } catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Authentication is failed");
        }
    }


Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> getJwtAuthenticationConverter() {
        TokenAuthenticationConverter converter = new TokenAuthenticationConverter(xsuaaServiceConfiguration);
        converter.setLocalScopeAsAuthorities(true);
        return converter;
    }
```

**application.yaml**

```html
spring:
  config.activate.on-profile: xsuaa
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:sqlite:file::memory:?cache=shared"
    driver-class-name: org.sqlite.JDBC
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always
      continue-on-error: true
cds:
  errors:
    extended: true
  security:
    xsuaa:
      enabled: true
    mock:
      enabled: false
    authentication:
      mode: always
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to allow all url's except `/RemoteHandlerServices/Handle`.

The problem is that you have a `.denyAll()` modifier next to matcher that matches all the url's. You should have `.permitAll()` instead, which would permit requests to urls that match your matcher (`/**` - which means any url).

Comment: sorry, i want to deny all request except /RemoteHandlerServices/Handle

Comment: please read more about spring authentication here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html.
You should have something like `auth.antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/RemoteHandlerServices/Handle").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()`